# Call private method in seam component

Tags: java, reflection, jboss-seam

Is there a way to invoke private methods in Seam Component. I used the following code but I found that there is no private methods in declared methods. So, I get ***NoSuchMethodException***.

```
Object obj = Component.getInstance("myComponent");
Method myMethod = obj.getClass.getDeclaredMethod("myPrivateMethod",String.class);
myMethod.invoke(obj,"myParameter");
```

Comment: Why would you want to invoke a private method to begin with? Looks more like a code smell using this reflection. It would be better changing the visibility of the method to `protected` or `public`.

Comment: It is because the component class is in customized framework jar file. So I can't call or change it directly. But I have to call it to do auto login process. That private method is called in **Login** method but I have to invoke without calling **Login** method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `setAccessible`  `true`.

```
 Method myMethod = obj.getClass.getDeclaredMethod("myPrivateMethod",String.class);
 method.setAccessible(true);
 Object r = myMethod.invoke(obj,"myParameter");
```

**A value of true indicates that the reflected object should suppress Java language access checking when it is used. for more look in [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible%28boolean%29).**

Comment: Yes, I did setAccessible(true) but the problem is the private methods are not included in declared method array.